# gVim - Ubuntu - Window keeps resizing

Tags: vim, ubuntu, autoresize, window-management

I'm in Ubuntu using gVim.  Something is just wrong with the Window management of gVim - it keeps resizing on me!   ...  It usually happens when I either switch tabs or split the window or switch between splits.

Any help would be completely awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might just be the scrollbars. If you don't care about them:

```
:setglobal guioptions-=L
:setglobal guioptions-=l
:setglobal guioptions-=R
:setglobal guioptions-=r
:setglobal guioptions-=b
:setglobal guioptions-=h
```

---

Probably less relevant, but related:

The menu bar may exhibit the same kind of behaviour depending on (the amount of) plugins loaded. Also, you *can* opt for the 'ascii' tab button bar

```
:setglobal guioptions-=e
```

Comment: (I was assuming you are a sir... but I could be mistaken).

THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I have been having so much pain with this for so long!!!!!    No, I don't care about the scrollbars (vim is all about the no mouse, right?) :)